# When is the image of a line bundle again a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, line-bundles

Hello everybody
**Motivation of my question**
Let $X$ be a scheme.
Given a morphism $\mathcal{L}\overset{\beta}\to\mathcal{O}_X$ of line bundles over $X$.
I want to understand under what conditions the image $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$ is a line bundle. I will specify my question below. To avoid trivialities, lets assume the morphism is not surjective.

**I already know the following results**

- If $X$ is a smooth curve over a field, then every non-zero coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-submodule of a line bundle is already a line bundle*. 
  Because $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$ is coherent and non-zero, we see that $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$ is a line bundle in this case.
- If $X$ has the property, that every local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a PID, then 
  the submodule $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)_x=\mathrm{Im}(\beta_x)\subseteq \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is free of rank $1$, which implies that $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$ is free, by finite presentedness of $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$.

**My question**
What if $X$ is a smooth scheme over a base scheme $S$, say of relative dimension $1$, for example? I am mainly interested in the case of a morphism $\mathcal{L}\overset{\beta}{\to} \mathcal{O}_{X_S}$ (non-surjective), where $X_S=S\times_{\mathrm{Spec}{k}}X$ where $S$ is any scheme over a field $k$ and $X$ is a smooth irreducible curve over $k$. Under what conditions is the image $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$ a line bundle?

**Some of my ideas**
Maybe one can prove that the restriction of $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$ to the fibres $X_S\to \mathrm{Spec}(\kappa(s))$ are line bundles, by using the first result from above and then conclude, that $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$ is a line bundle?
Alternatively one could try to understand the properties of the local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X_S,x}$, but I have doubts that they have any useful properties?

**PS:**

*This follows by the fact that the stalks are valuation rings and that torsion-free modules over valuation rings are flat by [Tag 0539](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0539), and the fact that over finitely generated flat modules over a local ring are free by [Matsumura, Commutative Algebra, Prop. 3G, page 21], and a standard Argument about finitely presented modules.

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand the question. If the image of $\beta$ is a line bundle, then isn't $\beta$ just an isomorphism? In particular I don't think your statement proof for the case of smooth curves works.

Comment: Hello user 45878, can You explain why it should be an Isomorphism? The morphism $\mathcal{L}\subseteq \mathcal{L}(D)$($D$ effective) has image $\mathcal{L}$ and is not in general an isomorphism. Or do You mean the morphism $\mathcal{L}\to \mathrm{Im}(\beta)$? So You claim, that every Morphism of line bundles is injective?

Comment: @user45878 Let $x$ be a closed point of $X$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is regular. In particular $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a valuation ring.  If $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{L}$ is a coherent submodule, and $x$ a closed point, then $\mathcal{M}_x$ is finitely generated and torsion free. Hence it is flat and finitely generated. Over local rings, this implies freeness. So $\mathcal{M}_x$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module of rank $1$ for every closed point. This implies, that for every closed point, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\mathcal{M}\mid_U\cong \mathcal{O}_U$.

Comment: Why is it not possible that $\mathcal{M}_x$ has rank zero?

Comment: So You agree, that $\mathcal{M}_x$ is a finite rank free $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module of rank $\leq 1$ but You don't agree, that it needs to be of rank $1$ right? I think You are right and I should add the hypothesis, that $X$ is connected. In this case, we see, that the rank of $\mathcal{M}_x$ is locally constant and hence, if it would be $0$, then this would imply $\mathcal{M}\cong \mathcal{O}_X^0=0$, but we did assume, that $\mathcal{M}\not=0$. Do You agree?

Comment: There is no reason for the rank of $\mathcal{M}_x$ to be locally constant (unless $\mathcal{M}$ is a line bundle, which is what we are trying to prove).

Comment: The reason that I had in mind was that the module is of finite presentation. Compare https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B8J

Comment: 1) It is not true that the rank of a coherent sheaf is locally constant, it is only semicontinuous in general